# jquery call a function outsite

Tags: jquery

i have a problem when i call a function from another file js.

i have a.html with the content.

```
<html>
<head>  
<script src="${resource(dir: 'js/demo', file: '.js')}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
updateConfigurationMap ({
    urlaa:'${createLink(controller: 'cc', action: 'bb')}',
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <select from="" onchange="checkRequiredInformation(this.value)" />
</body>
</html>
```

and i have a folder js/demo and demo.js inside this folder

```
function checkRequiredInformation (tt){
    if(tt!= "") {    
        $('#dd').load(configurationMap.urlaa);
    } else {
     $('#dd').html("");
    }
};
```

i have an error : Failed to load resource .... the url not correct .... but if i take this script into the same file ... everything is ok ? please help me seperated this function to another file . thanks

Comment: Is the script you're loading is from different domain?

Comment: Using Visualstudio ?, the  directly drag the script file it will create the reference.

Comment: it's on the same . and i'm using groovy on grails

Comment: Well, what does the generate HTML look like? The URL to the script is wrong so you must correct it. Only you can know what the correct URL is. There is not much we can do.

Comment: The resource inclusion is incorrect. It should read `${resource(dir: 'js/demo', file: 'demo.js')}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
<script src="/js/demo/demo.js"  type="javascript" language="javascript"/>
```